# How to do a "compact push"

Tags: angular-gridster2

e.g. in this demo https://tiberiuzuld.github.io/angular-gridster2/push 
[image]

When I move item 2 to the top, 1 and 3 are moved down and an empty row (4) is added:
[image]

I could not find a way to get rid of this empty row: i.e. I'd like to get this result after moving 1 to the top:

[image]

Is there a setting or other way to get this behaviour?

Comment: see [angular-gridster2#432](https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-gridster2/issues/432)